# Typescript cloudformation template typings?

Tags: typescript, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-sam, aws-cdk-typescript

I'm working on a tool to create AWS SAM templates using typescript, and was wondering if there's any template typings for TS/generators for creating them programmatically? Ideally I'd like to do something like:

```js
const template: CloudFormationTemplate = {
  Description: 'The template',
  ...
}
```

or

```js
const template: CloudFormationTemplate = new CloudFormation.Template({
  Description: 'The template',
  ...
})
```

Comment: FWIW: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudform